# How to connect a Windows Service to the Console session

Tags: c++, windows, service, remote-desktop

I've been developing a remote desktop application which runs as a Windows service, and I was wondering how I could connect the application to a specific session, and allow it to retrieve the user's desktop as a bitmap, set the cursor position, send mouse clicks, and keyboard input to the console session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`SetThreadDesktop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686250%28VS.85%29.aspx) to change the thread's context in your service to the user's desktop.

- `SetThreadDesktop()` takes a handle to the desktop as it's first parameter;  to get that handle, use [`EnumDesktops()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682614%28VS.85%29.aspx).
- `EnumDesktops()` takes a handle to the window station as it's first parameter; to get that handle, use [`EnumWindowStations()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682644%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

To understand what's going on with Window Stations and Desktops, try reading [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681928%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from from MSDN.

Finally, be cautious with this technique.  Higher-privileged processes (i.e., services) interacting with the user's desktop are the basis for [shatter attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack).